# CLIPS(templates) - family relations: trouble with handling templates and initial facts while writing rules

Tags: clips, expert-system

I am struggling with the following CLIPS programming problem:

**Problem**:  write a set of rules to define family relations like:

(brother ?x ?y) (i.e. "x is a brother of y")

(sister ?x ?y) (i.e. "x is a sister of y")

(son ?x ?y) (i.e. "x is a son of y")

(daughter ?x ?y) (i.e. "x is a daughter of y")

The constraint in this task is that the rules can be constructed only from the following premises:

(father ?x ?y) (i.e. "x is a father of y")

(mother ?x ?y) (i.e. "x is a mother of y")

(male ?x) (i.e. "x is a male")

(female ?y) (i.e. "y is a female")

The task also assumes that there must be some initial facts provided and that to check the correctness there should be an implementation of displaying information about derived conclusions.

**My attempt**

I created templates and initial facts as follows:

```
(deftemplate father-of 
    (slot father)
    (slot child)
)

(deftemplate mother-of 
    (slot mother)
    (slot child)
)

(deftemplate male
    (slot person)
)

(deftemplate female
    (slot person)
 )

(deffacts family
      (mother-of(mother Anna) (child Tracy)
      (mother-of(mother Anna) (child Cindy)
      (female Anna)
      (female Tracy)
      (female Cindy)
 )
```

My attempt in writing a rule for checking if certain person is a sister of other person was as follows:

```
(defrule sister-of
      (and
           (female (person ?x))
           (female (person ?y))
           (female (person ?z))
           (mother-of (mother ?x) (child ?y))
           (mother-of (mother ?x) (child ?z))
       )
=>
(assert (sister ?y  ?z))
(printout t ?y " is a sister of " ?z crlf)
)
```

**Output error**

Once I load .clp file I consistenly obtain the following error message of such form:

```
         CLIPS (6.30 3/17/15)
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (load family.clp)
Defining deftemplate: father-of
Defining deftemplate: mother-of
Defining deftemplate: male
Defining deftemplate: female
Defining deffacts: family

[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for deftemplate pattern.

ERROR:
(deffacts MAIN::family
   (mother-of (mother Anna) (child Markus))
   (female Anna
FALSE
CLIPS>
```

**My attempts**

I checked CLIPS guides regarding basic programming, googled error message, but I did not make any progress.

Help will be greatly appreciated!!! For me it suffices to see how this stuff works in the case of the case of writing a rule (sister ?x ?y) with all the templates and facts provided above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a deftemplate for a fact, you must include the slot names when specifying the slot values.

```
(deffacts family
      (mother-of(mother Anna) (child Tracy))
      (mother-of(mother Anna) (child Cindy))
      (female (person Anna))
      (female (person Tracy))
      (female (person Cindy))
 )
```